# Apache2 module Filebeat

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I'm following  this  documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-apache2.html  in order to connect an apache web server access  log file using file beat to elasticsearch, everything was ok until I changed  the  path of  **apache2.yml** I got the following error  :

```
2018-09-22T14:21:55.791+0100    ERROR   instance/beat.go:691    Exiting: 1 error: error
loading config file: invalid config: yaml: line 3: found unknown escape character
Exiting: 1 error: error loading config file: invalid config: yaml: line 3: found unknown escape character
```

this  id  apache2.yml configuration file :

```
    - module: apache2
  access:
    enabled: true
    var.paths: ["‪C:\Program Files\filebeat-6.3.2-windows\logs\Apache\Access.log"]
```

Comment: Have you tried to double the backslashes? i.e. \\ instead of \

Comment: nope  I'll try it , I hope it works  !

Comment: To use the Apache  module have  I set up the  filebeat.yml too coz  in the  official documentation, I didn't see any requirement about it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using double quotes in

```
"‪C:\Program Files\filebeat-6.3.2-windows\logs\Apache\Access.log"
```

you need to escape the backslash characters

```
"‪C:\\Program Files\\filebeat-6.3.2-windows\\logs\\Apache\\Access.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use / instead of . \ is used to escape characters.
I had the same problem